# The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

There seems to be a lot of these errors found on the forum, but I can't apply most of them on my situation..

**My problem:**

I have a page: PosterHome.xaml, with a uniform grid on it.
In my code-behind, I have a drawthread:

```
drawThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(drawPosters));
                drawThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                drawThread.Start();
```

This threadmethod (drawPosters) is occasionally woken up by another class, using a autoresetevent. I get the error in this method the moment i'm changing the uniform grid rows:

```
while (true)
{
  waitEvent.WaitOne();
  //do some calculations
  // change uniform grid rows & cols
  posterUniformGrid.Rows = calculatedRows; //**-> error is first thrown here**
  posterUniformGird.Columns = calculatedCols;             
}
```

How should I handle this? Thanks in advance.

Greets Daan

Comment: Which forum posts did you look at and why don't they apply to your situation?  Did you look for posts about Dispatcher?

Comment: If you had googled exactly the title of your question, the first hit had given you a profound explanation of what's going on.

Comment: I did try using a dispatcher, but apparently i did something wrong because it didn't work for me..but I used the example aaron gave and it worked!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're attempting to access `posterUniformGrid` which was created on the UI thread from your background thread.

To avoid this, leverage the [Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx).

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, 
                    new Action<object[]>(SetGrid), 
                    new object[] { calculatedRows, calculatedColumns });
```

Comment: +1. Yup : This is even more WPF compliant than my old-school answer

Answer (score 0):

You could try this :

```
 while (true)
 {
   waitEvent.WaitOne();
   this.InvokeEx(t => t.posterUniformGrid.Rows = calculatedRows); 
   this.InvokeEx(t => t.posterUniformGird.Columns = calculatedCols);             
 }

 public static class ISynchronizeInvokeExtensions
    {
        public static void InvokeEx<T>(this T @this, Action<T> action) where T : ISynchronizeInvoke
        {
            if (@this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                try
                {
                    @this.Invoke(action, new object[] { @this });
                }
                catch { }
            }
            else
            {
                action(@this);
            }
        }
    }
```